# Data Archival Vs Data Ingestion

Tags: bigdata, erp

What exactly is the difference between **Data Archival** and **Data Ingestion** in a Big Data or Data Lake perspective ?  I Presume in a Data Lake context "Ingestion" would be the proper word, but what all aspects we would be missing if we use 'Archival' there instead of 'Ingestion'.

Few reasons i think of to use 'Ingestion' instead of 'Archival' are

- If the context relates to Data Lake
- If there are multiple source systems(If it is a one to one migration from a source to target it is more of a kind of archival)

Is my understanding correct.  Would like to know various other reasons as well

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Data Archival**: after a certain time period, active data get archived as passive data in data lake

**Data Ingestion**: continuously loading the data in data lake